# How to make these 2 long tables look better?

Tags: tables

Please, I need to your help to make these two long tables look better. Also, please, I will highly appreciate your help if you put comments on the packages and commands that may be used in order to understand how they work.

The tables are:
[image]

The code:
T5

```
\begin{table}[htb]
\caption{The state-of-the-art in taxonomy, detection, extraction and pattern recognition in urban applications}
\label{T2.5}
\centering
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{| l | l | l | l | l |}
        \hline
        \textbf{Application} & \textbf{Taxonomy/quantification algorithms} & \textbf{Merits} & \textbf{Limitations} & \textbf{Example}  \\ 
        \hline
        \multirow{5}{*}{} Seismic building structural types (SBSTs) & Support vector machine (SVM) and random forest (RF) & Classify the combination of different remote sensing data & Hierarchical supervised classification scheme has uncertainties in separating SBSTs & \cite{geiss2015}   \\ \cline{2-5} 
        & & Derive sets of valuable features to characterise the urban environment & Performance depends on the ranked features & \\ \cline{2-5} 
        & & Model an effective earthquake loss and spatial distribution & Accuracy is subject to the addition of further features and subset based categories & \\ \cline{2-5} 
        & & ABTSVM classifier outperforms other multi-class SVM classifiers &  & \\ \cline{2-5}
        \hline 
        \multirow{5}{*}{} Urban change detection: landuse transitions & Scene classification with a bag-of-visual-words (BOVW) & Obtain semantic scene classes & Time-consuming & \cite{wu2016}   \\ \cline{2-5} 
        & & Effectively analyse landuse changes & Very difficult to achieve the direct selection of the “from-to” samples from the dataset & \\ \cline{2-5} 
        & & Satisfactory accuracy & Classification performance in certain cases is negatively affected by the redundancy of information & \\ \cline{2-5} 
        \hline
        \multirow{5}{*}{} Urban landcover and landuse classification & Binary tree SVM based on Jeffries–Matusita (JM) distance & Improve classification accuracy & Confusion between road and bare soil classes & \cite{du2012}   \\ \cline{2-5}
        & & Classify hyperspectral images adequately & Instability and complexity in the structure and parameters of the binary tree SVM & \\ \cline{2-5} 
        & & Ease of interpretation of urban classes & & \\ \cline{2-5} 
        \hline
        \multirow{5}{*}{} Monitoring changes in impervious surfaces & MRGU & Integrate multiple endmember spectral mixture analysis (MESMA) & Not universally applicable due to specific behaviour of maximum noise fraction (MNF) & \cite{shahtahmassebi2016}   \\ \cline{2-5}
        & & Analysis of regression residuals & Difficult to use for quantifying changes in urban centres & \\ \cline{2-5} 
        & & Spatial statistics (Getis Ord) with Moran’s I & Performance (regression residuals) is subject to the structure of urban regions & \\ \cline{2-5} 
        & & Urban growth theories in an effective manner & & \\ \cline{2-5} 
        & & Quantify the magnitude of impervious surface changes & & \\ \cline{2-5} 
        & & Identify spatial distribution& & \\ \cline{2-5} 
        \hline
        \multirow{5}{*}{} Change detection & Unsupervised Neural network and feature transformation & SDAE for better representation of the relationships between feature- and pixel-pair & Uncertainty in the feature-pair & \cite{zhang2016}   \\ \cline{2-5}
        & & Mapping based FCA and function learning to highlight change in a robust manner & High computational cost & \\ \cline{2-5} 
        & & Denoising autoencoder & Complexity structures of stacked denoising autoencoders (SDAE) & \\ \cline{2-5}
        & & & Many constraints are required to extract useful features & \\ \cline{2-5}
        \hline
        \multirow{5}{*}{} Water quality, and sustainable water resources management & Integrated data fusion and mining (IDFM) and artificial neural network (ANN) & A near real-time monitoring and the early warning system & Prediction accuracy may be effected by uncertainties in the fused data & \cite{imen2015}   \\ \cline{2-5}
        & & Efficiency & A large number of variables is required to overcome the uncertainty & \\ \cline{2-5}
        & & Forecasting reliability & Not applicable for regional meteorology parameters & \\ \cline{2-5}
        & & Potential for local adoption & & \\ \cline{2-5}
        \hline
        \multirow{5}{*}{} Air temperature estimation & SVM & Fully automated method & Requires expert users to apply SVM & \cite{moser2015}   \\ \cline{2-5}
        & & SVM regression is robust & Does not work well under non cloud-free conditions and require in situ measurements & \\ \cline{2-5}
        & & Regression errors can be modelled at the pixel level, improving accuracy estimation & Regression error distribution is insufficient & \\ \cline{2-5}
        \hline
        \multirow{5}{*}{} Fine-scale population estimation for urban management, emergency response and epidemiological & RF and Linear regression modelling & Able to classify building types and extract their footprints in the heterogeneous urban areas & Subject to the accuracy of the selected morphology filter & \cite{xie2015}   \\ \cline{2-5}
        & & Improved classification accuracy & Use of large numbers of metrics and variables for building type classification & \\ \cline{2-5}
        & & Ease of adoption & Building background metrics do not show its advantage in the block classification & \\ \cline{2-5}
        & & & Classification uncertainty for non-residential buildings & \\ \cline{2-5}
        \hline
        \multirow{5}{*}{} Renewable energy and urban feature extraction & Shadow detection and building geometry identification & Easy to apply & Semi-automated  & \cite{kadhim2015a}   \\ \cline{2-5}
        & & Sufficient to generate 3D model of urban buildings & Not suitable for dense urban areas & \\ \cline{2-5}
        & & Reliable analysis of the solar energy potential & Sensitive to the quality of satellite images & \\ \cline{2-5}
        & & Identify the availability of 3D surfaces & & \\ \cline{2-5}
        & & Flexibility and feasibility & & \\ \cline{2-5}
        \hline
        \multirow{5}{*}{} Impervious surfaces estimation & SVM and RF & Increased classification accuracy & Needs many texture matrices  & \cite{zhang2015}   \\ \cline{2-5}
        & & Sufficient to generate 3D model of urban buildings & Not suitable for dense urban areas & \\ \cline{2-5}
        & & Does not depend on combinations of features & Inability to handle the confusion in shaded areas and bare soil & \\ \cline{2-5}
        & & Data can be fused to optimise parameters efficiently & Over-fitting & \\ \cline{2-5}
        & & Ease of application & & \\ \cline{2-5}

        \hline
    \end{tabular}
}

\end{table}
```

and the second one, T6 is:

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Directions of future research}
\label{T2.6}
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \cline{2-7}
    & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\textbf{Integration of heterogeneous data}} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\textbf{Algorithms to identify urban features}} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\textbf{Improve accuracy for spectral classification algorithms}} \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Objective}} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} Improve the spatial and spectral resolution\\ Enhance the ability of features detection and display\\ Promote the geometric precision\\ Increase the capability of the change detection\\ Refine, replace or repair the defect of image data\\ Refine, replace or repair the defect of image data\\ Handle multi-source remote sensing data at the pixel, feature and decision of level fusion\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} Accelerate future processing and improve classification accuracy\\ Automated processes for detecting, extracting, simulating, classifying and modelling urban features\\ Capability of handling and fusing the large number of datasets\\ Improve image objects segmentation\\ Increase the reliability and precision of the feature extraction\\ Mitigate the ambiguous and uncertainty\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} Capability of separating urban land-cover and land-use classes in an adequate manner\\ For a better visualisation and interpretation of urban landscape\\ Performing a change detection analysis and pattern recognition\\ Accurately characterise the model parameters for different urban remote sensing applications\end{tabular}}      \\ \hline

    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{sfre} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}A rescaling of multisource data of divers EO instruments\\Assessing the distortion of the spatial and spectral resolution\\ Time-consuming and subjective\\ The complexity and/or availability of a large training datasets for the deep learning features\\ Manual or semi-automated the post-processing process\\ Computation efficiency and effectiveness\\ The quality of the distinguishing features\\ With the fusion schemes, the optimal combining strategy of the current fusion algorithms is a challenging task and promising research that requires further investigations in the near future
     \end{tabular}}           & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Further developments for fusing LiDAR data with thermal, multispectral and hyperspectral imagery\\ Reliable determination of the boundaries of urban objects in an automated manner\\ Further improvements for addressing different characteristics of EO data\\Ability to cope with unpredictable environmental and illumination factors of diverse datasets\\ Similarity in the characteristics of spectral, textural and geometrical-based between the urban objects and their background\\ Similarity in the characteristics of spectral, textural and geometrical-based between the urban objects and their background\\ Computational time to perform a task\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Mixed pixels\\ Uncertainty in the urban land-cover and land-use classes\\Mixed objects\\Promote pixel-based and object-based classification using contextual information\\ Over-fitting can cause speckled results that are difficult to interpret\\ An automatic labelling strategy is required for actual label sets in several applications\\ Further refinements for the fusion of diverse data sources\\ Integrate the derived urban features (e.g. building shadows) and/or spatial matrices with various classifier schemes\\ Investigate the recent computer vision techniques for improving the accuracy \end{tabular}} \\ \hline


\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
```

I will highly appreciate any help that may I get.

This is the beginning of my thesis doc. code:

```
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
%% Thesis.tex -- MAIN FILE (the one that you compile with LaTeX)
%% ---------------------------------------------------------------- 

% Set up the document

\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, arial, oneside]{Thesis}   % Use the "Thesis" style, based on the ECS Thesis style by Steve Gunn

\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage[scaled=0.92]{helvet}
%\usepackage [T1] {fontenc}
%\renewcommand\familydefault{phv}
```

[image]

Comment: How wide is the text block? What's the default font and font size?

Comment: Welcome to tex stackexchange! I can't run the LaTeX code. What packages are you running? Are you doing PDFLaTeX or something else?

You should try and provide a [minimum working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) as seen in this link, it helps us all help you.

Comment: Without knowing at least the margins and page size, nobody will be able to help. You already know that.

Comment: How about splitting it into multiple tables? E.g. create a subsection for each application in table 5, where you describe the application and its challenges in a few words, show the examples (including a very brief description of the example), and finally have a separate table with pro/con for each application?

Comment: Is this a two-column layout?

Comment: These two tables (at least their code) look very much the same as the one in your previous question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/392672/134144). Maybe you should have a look at the answers from Johannes_B and  Zarko there, as most of the tips from them can be applied to the tables of this question as well.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments. I edited my post and hopefully it shows the margins and page size. It is just one column layout. I have a look on the previous answers and I have started to amend these two tables but still there is a problem with the page borders and the width and length of the table (dimension). I will post a snapshot of this issue with this post.

Comment: @Iris: Thanks for editing your post. Your table already looks a lot better now. Unfortunately the code to this table is still missing. Could you please as well tell us where you got the `Thesis` class from?

Comment: @Iris, i'm pretty much sure that your question is duplicate (at least regarding to the problem) to your previous question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392672/how-can-i-make-this-table-looks-better-using-latex. just use suggestions provided in gotten answers. not expect, that someone here will do this instead of you.

Comment: consider to rotate table with help of `lscape` or `pdflscape` package (`\begin{landscape} ... your table ... \end{landscape}`) or `rotating` package (`\begin{sidewaystable} ... your table ... \end{sidewaystable}`). for table formatting use suggestion given in answers to your previous (very similar) question.

Comment: Why did you decide to use thst template and where did you get it from? That specific template got me nightmares. Is it the one from Sunil?

Comment: There are about a zillion LaTeX document classes called `Thesis`. Which one would you be using? Can it be downloaded from somewhere?

Comment: You should stay away from `resizebox`. If you are working with a  table converter that produces that thing, you should stay away from that converter ;-)

Comment: I think it would be better if you share your solution to your problems by writing up a self answer instead of deleting the question.

Comment: @Johannes_B - I'll do that next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just adoption of my answer on your previous question ([how-can-i-make-this-table-looks-better-using-latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392672/how-can-i-make-this-table-looks-better-using-latex)), for table data is used and modified table body from [Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/mico) answer ... and add new looks of lists of data -):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage[scaled=0.92]{helvet}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set width of textblock appropriately
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X}
\usepackage[skip=1ex,labelfont=bf,font=small]{caption}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{%
    \setlist[itemize]{nosep,
                      wide,%leftmargin = *,
                      before     = \vspace{-\baselineskip},
                      after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                        }
                           }% end of AtBeginEnvironment

%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{1} % just for this example
\setcounter{table}{5} % just for this example

\begin{table}[htbp]
\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt} % default: 6pt
\caption{Directions for future research} \label{T2.6}
%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}p{9ex} L L L}
\toprule
    &
    Integration of heterogeneous data &
    Algorithms to identify urban features &
    Improve accuracy for spectral classification algorithms \\
\midrule
    Objective &
    \begin{itemize}
    \item   Improve the spatial and spectral resolution
    \item   Enhance the ability of features detection and display
    \item   Promote the geometric precision
    \item   Increase the capability of the change detection
    \item   Refine, replace or repair the defect of image data
    \item   Refine, replace or repair the defect of image data
    \item   Handle multi-source remote sensing data at the pixel, feature and
    decision of level fusion
    \end{itemize}
    &
    \begin{itemize}
    \item   Accelerate future processing and improve classification accuracy
    \item   Automated processes for detecting, extracting, simulating, classifying and modelling urban features
    \item   Capability of handling and fusing the large number of datasets
    \item   Improve image objects segmentation
    \item   Increase the reliability and precision of the feature extraction
    \item   Mitigate the ambiguous and uncertainty
    \end{itemize}
    &
    \begin{itemize}
    \item   Capability of separating urban land-cover and land-use classes in an adequate manner
    \item   For a better visualisation and interpretation of urban landscape
    \item   Performing a change detection analysis and pattern recognition
    \item   Accurately characterise the model parameters for different urban remote sensing applications
    \end{itemize}       \\
\midrule
    Problems requiring solutions
    &
    \begin{itemize}
    \item   A rescaling of multisource data of divers EO instruments
    \item   Assessing the distortion of the spatial and spectral resolution Time-consuming and subjective
    \item   The complexity and\slash or availability of a large training datasets for the deep learning features
    \item   Manual or semi-automated the post-processing process Computation efficiency and effectiveness
    \item   The quality of the distinguishing features
    \item   With the fusion schemes, the optimal combining strategy of the current fusion algorithms is a challenging task and promising research that requires further investigations in the near future
    \end{itemize}
    &
    \begin{itemize}
    \item   Further developments for fusing LiDAR data with thermal, multispectral and hyperspectral imagery
    \item   Reliable determination of the boundaries of urban objects in an automated manner
    \item   Further improvements for addressing different characteristics of EO data
    \item   Ability to cope with unpredictable environmental and illumination factors of diverse datasets
    \item   Similarity in the characteristics of spectral, textural and geometrical-based between the urban objects and their background
    \item   Similarity in the characteristics of spectral, textural and geometrical-based between the urban objects and their background
    \item   Computational time to perform a task
    \end{itemize}
    &
     \begin{itemize}
    \item   Mixed pixels
    \item   Uncertainty in the urban land-cover and land-use classes
    \item   Mixed objects
    \item   Promote pixel-based and object-based classification using contextual information
    \item   Over-fitting can cause speckled results that are difficult to interpret
    \item   An automatic labelling strategy is required for actual label sets in several applications
    \item   Further refinements for the fusion of diverse data sources
    \item   Integrate the derived urban features (e.g., building shadows) and\slash or spatial matrices with various classifier schemes
    Investigate the recent computer vision techniques for improving the accuracy
    \end{itemize}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**edit:** it seems that `tabularx` was not worked as i expected. therefore i change

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}>{\hsize=0.4\hsize}L *{3}{>{\hsize=1.2\hsize}L}@{}}
```

to

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}p{9ex} LLL @{}}
```

consequently now text in cells are better fit and table is less tall.

**addendum:**

- your question is very opinion based. different people have different taste :-) and promote different solutions,
- however the first rule in table design is *be consistent*. if ones you decided for some table style, than you should use it in all tables. also if you have lists in tables, in all tables had to be of the same form.
- special problem are tables with long text in cells. in such cases is sensible to use `\small` font size for table contents. with it the text will better fit into cells.
- you should keep in mind that latex expect that on the page is about 1/3 of text. if your table are longer, consider to use `longtable` or `ltablex` for write it over more pages.
- in table design is advisable consider good practice, which can be find on internet, for example ["Less is More"](https://wiert.me/2014/04/03/andre-vatter-google-wie-tabellen-eigentlich-aussehen-sollten-%EF%BB%BF/) etc

Comment: +1 for the wide/nosep/before/after options for `itemize` enviroments.

Comment: @Zarko: Thank you very much for your help. I implemented the code and it is so pretty. However, the length of the table exceeds the length of the page again. Please, how can make it within one page only. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Iris, see edited answer. regarding height of my table: you not select my answer, so you will not have problem with resulted table height :-). happy text-ing!

Comment: @Mico, thank you. also +1 from me :-). and congratulation for acceptance of your answer! if you wouldn't write it I would suggest to close question as to broad.

Comment: @Zarko - Thanks! :-) I've actually asked the OP to delete the first table from her/his query. In my view, the first table is nearly impenetrable; finding a pleasing (and correct!) modification is not likely to happen. The OP needs figure out what's essential about this exceedingly long and detailed table, restructure the table accordingly, and then (if, and only if, still needed) post a new query.

Comment: @Zarko - Thanks a lot. I highly appreciate your help. All of you are amazing :)

Comment: Congrats on getting the (delayed) acceptance! :-)

Comment: @Mico, thank you. i'm not sure, if this is permanent or temporary decision. once this op twice change the mind regarding my answer :-(

Answer (score 3):

Here's a stab a the second, i.e., smaller of the two tables you're working on. I believe it's a lot more legible now.

Note that I don't have access to your document class. I've substituted the generic `report` class.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage[scaled=0.92]{helvet}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set width of textblock appropriately
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx,tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\setlength\parskip{0.2\baselineskip}\arraybackslash}X}
\setlength\extrarowheight{1pt}
\usepackage{caption}
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth{\mylen}{Objective} % measure width of longest word in 1st col.

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{1} % just for this example
\setcounter{table}{5} % just for this example

\begin{table}[htbp]
\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default: 6pt
\captionsetup{font=small,skip=0.333\baselineskip}
\caption{Directions for future research} \label{T2.6}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} p{\mylen} LLL @{}}
\toprule
    & 
    Integration of heterogeneous data & 
    Algorithms to identify urban features & 
    Improve accuracy for spectral classification algorithms \\ 
\midrule
    Objective & 
    Improve the spatial and spectral resolution \par
    Enhance the ability of features detection and display \par
    Promote the geometric precision \par
    Increase the capability of the change detection \par
    Refine, replace or repair the defect of image data \par
    Refine, replace or repair the defect of image data \par
    Handle multi-source remote sensing data at the pixel, feature and
    decision of level fusion & 
    Accelerate future processing and improve classification accuracy\par
    Automated processes for detecting, extracting, simulating, classifying and modelling urban features\par
    Capability of handling and fusing the large number of datasets\par
    Improve image objects segmentation\par
    Increase the reliability and precision of the feature extraction\par
    Mitigate the ambiguous and uncertainty & 
    Capability of separating urban land-cover and land-use classes in an adequate manner\par
    For a better visualisation and interpretation of urban landscape\par
    Performing a change detection analysis and pattern recognition\par
    Accurately characterise the model parameters for different urban remote sensing applications \\ 
\midrule
    Problems requiring solutions & 
    A rescaling of multisource data of divers EO instruments\par
    Assessing the distortion of the spatial and spectral resolution\par Time-consuming and subjective\par
    The complexity and\slash or availability of a large training datasets for the deep learning features\par
    Manual or semi-automated the post-processing process\par Computation efficiency and effectiveness\par
    The quality of the distinguishing features\par
    With the fusion schemes, the optimal combining strategy of the current 
      fusion algorithms is a challenging task and promising research that 
      requires further investigations in the near future & 
    Further developments for fusing LiDAR data with thermal, multispectral and hyperspectral imagery\par
    Reliable determination of the boundaries of urban objects in an automated manner\par
    Further improvements for addressing different characteristics of EO data\par
    Ability to cope with unpredictable environmental and illumination factors of diverse datasets\par
    Similarity in the characteristics of spectral, textural and geometrical-based between the urban objects and their background\par
    Computational time to perform a task & 
    Mixed pixels\par
    Uncertainty in the urban land-cover and land-use classes\par
    Mixed objects\par
    Promote pixel-based and object-based classification using contextual information\par
    Over-fitting can cause speckled results that are difficult to interpret\par
    An automatic labelling strategy is required for actual label sets in several applications\par
    Further refinements for the fusion of diverse data sources\par
    Integrate the derived urban features (e.g., building shadows) and\slash or spatial matrices with various classifier schemes\par
    Investigate the recent computer vision techniques for improving the accuracy 
    \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: https://github.com/johannesbottcher/templateConfusion Shoul give a link to the class and the history :-)

Comment: Thank you very much Mico, for your help and response. Please, "sfre" is not a correct word (sorry it was my fault), and it should be "Problems requiring solutions". When I changed it the first column in this table (the second table) became wider. Please, how can I make these 3 words beneath each other?

Comment: @Iris: You could for example change `{@{}lLLL@{}}` to `{@{}p{1.75cm}LLL@{}}` This way the width of the first column is exactly 1.75 cm and the contents are spread over three lines.

Comment: @leandriis: Thank you very much. The second table now looks better.

Comment: Please, I need your help with the first table. I am really grateful to you all. All of you are awesome. The last thing, please, the first table. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Iris - I'm not going to tackle the first table, simply because I don't "get" its structure. What's the relationship between the blocks in columns 2, 3, and 4? Do the items in the columns form a list per column -- like the material in the second column -- or is there some (so far still unclear) structure across rows 2, 3, and 4 that must be preserved? You may want to delete the first table from the present query, spend some time clarifying in your mind what the structure should be, modify the table code as needed, and then post a *new query* asking for further help (but only if still needed).

Comment: @Mico - Thank you for your help and your comment. You are absolutely right. However, I've learned from the code that you sent me how to manage it and make it look better. I highly appreciate your help and your time you gave me.