# Table with itemize inside

Tags: tables, itemize

Hello I would like to do one table like this:
[image]

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
\textbf{Strengths}     & \textbf{Weaknesses} \\ \hline
items here             & more items          \\ \hline
\textbf{Opportunities} & \textbf{Threats}    \\ \hline
items                  & iteems              \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I would like to do on each row of the table except the titles ones (Strengths, Weakness, Opportunities, Threats):

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item One entry in the list
  \item Another entry in the list
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: Welcome, why has your table three extra columns?

Comment: I am not sure where you have trouble. Can you elaborate what isn't working?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! A minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problemis always a good idea... starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Johannes_B I have already fixed that. I think now it's more clear. I just wanna add itemize on some rows of the table view.

Comment: As said in e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121220/itemize-in-tabular?rq=1#comment270695_121220 you can't have an `itemize` in an `l` column, you need to use `p{<width>}` instead. For example `p{5cm}`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. seems it's a duplicate question then. Should I delete it?

Comment: No need for deletion, we can mark it as duplicate. That way, other users can find the answer faster.

Comment: You can also have a look at the questions of [this user](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/144031/iris) or better at the answers the user got.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393494/how-to-make-these-2-long-tables-look-better/393525#393525 (as mentioned  @Johannes_B).